# Left Ctrl + C is not working in Ubuntu 16.04 while right Ctrl+C works

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

The <kbd>Left-Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Left-Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (for terminal) is not working in my Ubuntu 16.04 whereas other combinations with <kbd>Left-Ctrl</kbd> is working. The <kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd> key works for all combinations. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: left ctrl+v and other shortcuts work fine. Even the key C is ok. How can I check if its a hardware issue?

Comment: same here,, and no one know the problem ?